# How to change values of all instances from a pandas series of datetime64 dtype

Tags: python, pandas

A dataset has one column which has dates in the format of 'DD-MM-YY'. On Checking the values of years in the date column, it is noticed that some of the entries have been wrongly made as '12-nov-73' which should be '12-nov-13' . Upon loading the dataset in the dataframe the format gets converted into a datetime64 dtype with '1973' as one of the years. How do I replace all such values in the date column ?

```
date = df.LAST_RECEIPT_DATE
```

I extracted the column into a series

```
date.map(lambda t: t.date().year).unique()
```

that's how I checked for unique year values

```
 date[date.dt.year==1973].map(lambda t:t.replace(year=2013))
```

that's how I performed the replace operation . But, on assigning the above line to date it doesn't update the original series. How do i update the original column

Comment: You could also change the strings before parsing, right?

Comment: Adding a representative sample of your data together with desired output may help. See [mcve] for more.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a df:

```
df
    date
0   2012-11-12
1   1973-11-12
```

Then we can replace as:

```
df.date[df.date.dt.year == 1973] = df.date[df.date.dt.year == 1973].map(lambda t: dt.datetime(2012, t.month, t.day))
df

    date
0   2012-11-12
1   2012-11-12
```

Comment: yeah I eventually worked my way around it . Since date is a series, by placing the, date[date.dt.year==1973].map(lambda t:t.replace(year=2013)) , replace operation in pd.update() method, i was able to change all the relevant rows. I think update method would be computationally more efficient.